# How to make map.emplace automatically choose constructor in c++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap, emplace

In c++17 first, I have a struct like

```
typedef struct ST_A{
    int a;
    string s;

    ST_A(const int a, const string&s) :a(a),s(s) {}
}st_A;
```

And Now I have a simple map and emplace twice in terms of
[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace#:%7E:text=as%20of%20C%2B%2B17%2C%20m.try_emplace(%22c%22%2C%2010%2C%20%27c%27)%3B%20can%20be%20used)

```
map<string, st_A> m1;
m1.emplace("c", 10, "c");                   ---> case 1
m1.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,        ---> case 2
        std::forward_as_tuple("c"),
        std::forward_as_tuple(10, "c"));
```

Case 2 works fine but case 1 compiles in error. So how to solve it in case 1 and make `emplace` as concise as possible?

What if the `map` is much more complex? Like
`map<string, deque<pair<int, st_A>>> m2`, how to `emplace` it as concise as possible?

What if self-define struct has more constructors?Like

```
typedef struct ST_A{
    int a = 0;
    string s;

    ST_A(const int a) :a(a) {}
    ST_A(const string&s) :s(s) {}
    ST_A(const int a, const string&s) :a(a),s(s) {}
}st_A;
```

would it confuse the compiler if there actually is some consice way to `emplace` as the above link in cppreference.

---

**UPDATE**
If my original map is `map<string, deque<pair<int, st_A>>> m2`, and now I want to add an element of `pair{"c1", pair{1, st_A{10, "c"}}}`.That is to say, after adding, m2 changes into `map{{"c1",deque{pair{1,st_A{10, "c"}}}}`
with the form of `insert` codes is like

```
m2.insert({"c1", {{1, {10, "c"}}}});
```

but it may call too many ctor/copy ctor, if I want to write in a more efficient way in performance, how could it be?

Comment: The value type of a `std::map` is a `std::pair`; without piecewise_construct you are calling `pair`'s constructor, so the number of overloads of your own constructor is irrelevant

Comment: I think you want this `m1.emplace("c", st_A{10, "c"});` ? `emplace` in this case is looking at `std::pair` constructor so you need to give it 2 elements

Comment: Some minor remarks, You still use "C"'s style of declaring sturcts. `struct ST_A{  ...  };` is enough. Then later you can do `STA st_a;` when you need an intance. If you are still using `using namespace std;` in your code then don't do that.

Answer (score 5):

`emplace()` constructs `std::pair<const Key,Value>` from the passed arguments.

Without `std::piecewise_construct`, you have to pass exactly two arguments, one to construct the key, one to construct the value:

```
m1.emplace("c", st_A{10, "c"});
```

Which defeats the purpose of "emplacing" since you are constructing the value ahead of the call.

My recommendation is to use `try_emplace` which has a more friendly API, especially if the key is simple and allows exactly what you want:

```
auto [it, inserted ] = m1.try_emplace(Key{key_args...}, value_args...);
```

```
auto [it, inserted ] = m1.try_emplace("c", 10, "c");
```

In general, the first argument constructs the key, the rest construct the value. `Key` ctor can thus be omitted if it accepts just one argument.

The return value indicates whether the element has been `inserted` or if there is already an element with the same key present. `it` returns basically `m1.at("c")`.

The key is always constructed, the value arguments are only "consumed"(=moved from) if `inserted==true`. Otherwise they are untouched.

#### Example

For `map<string, deque<pair<int, st_A>>> m2;`, you could the the following:

```
m2["C"].emplace_back(1, st_A{10, "c"});
```

`std::deque` does not have a constructor that accepts a single element, aggregate initialization does not work either. Not that it would save any copies, `std::deque::emplace_back` achieves that already. So `m2["C"]` does the construction efficiently already.

If you want to also elide `st_A` temporary, you can again fallback to `std::pair`'s `std::piecewise_construct`:

```
m2["C"].emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1),
                     std::forward_as_tuple(10, "c"));
```

Comment: If my target map is `map<string, deque<pair<int, st_A>>> m2`, and now I want to insert an element of `pair{"c1", pair{1, st_A{10, "c"}}}`, how would I write to use as less ctor/copy ctor as possible?

Comment: @f1msch Added the example.

Comment: added under my original question